# "xsh", "mo", "msf" tags in Postscript

Tags: postscript

While investigating a Postscript file I find some tags like "xsh", "mo", "msf"
Can you please tell me what are the meaning of these tags.

They are appearing as

1. [some floating point numbers]xsh
2. v1 v2 mo
3. [m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6]msf

Here v1, v2 can be floating or just natural numbers
m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 are integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mo` is probably `moveto` and `msf` is probably `concat` or a matrix version of `scalefont`.

You'll have to search for the first occurrence of these commands in the file and see how they are `def`ined.

Apparently these are generated by Adobe Illustrator or InDesign. See [How do I stop an .EPS file from breaking text into multiple lines in PostScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892176/how-do-i-stop-an-eps-file-from-breaking-text-into-multiple-lines-in-postscript).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe they are normal postscript operators, perhaps they are procedures defined in the file?